# Can't get CSS grid to create an empty cell though all cells are rectangular

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to create a grid where the last cell on the first row is empty by using '.' with CSS grid-template-areas. As far as I am aware every shape is a rectangle.Here is the desired layout:

Contrast:    Default    Low 
Font-size:   Default    Large    Extra large 
Spacing:     Default    Wide     Extra wide

But it keeps coming out like this: 

Contrast:    Default    Low    Font-size:
Default      Large      Extra-large  Spacing: 
Default      Wide       Extra wide

I have copied from 3 different tutorials, but I am still stuck.

code:

```css
.1 {
  grid-area: 1;
}

.2 {
  grid-area: 2;
}

.3 {
  grid-area: 3;
}

.4 {
  grid-area: 4;
}

.5 {
  grid-area: 5;
}

.6 {
  grid-area: 6;
}

.7 {
  grid-area: 7;
}

.8 {
  grid-area: 8;
}

.9 {
  grid-area: 9;
}

.10 {
  grid-area: a;
}

.11 {
  grid-area: b;
}

.accessibilityGrid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "1 2 3 ." "4 5 6 7" "8 9 a b";
}
```

```html
<div class="accessibilityGrid">
  <div class="1">Contrast:</div>
  <div class="2">Default</div>
  <div class="3">Low</div>
  <div class="4">Font-size:</div>
  <div class="5">Default</div>
  <div class="6">Large</div>
  <div class="7">Extra large</div>
  <div class="8">Letter-spacing:</div>
  <div class="9">Default</div>
  <div class="10">Wide</div>
  <div class="11">Extra wide</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I do not think the duplicate helps you. Here the trouble is that you used plain numbers to set class names and also areas (twice a reason it won't work) . if you use plain numbers, use always a letter in front of them for id,class and areas https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QWKaqLb

Comment: @G-Cyrillus A link to/quote of the spec that mentions letter requirements for grid-area names might be helpful too.

Comment: @TylerH i was looking for an efficient duplicate here on SO( but probably missing the right english keywords ... idem for the spec , it must be standing on a notation page aside for global rule/standard )... :(

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I would guess https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-template-areas-property if anything -- if you're ever not sure about a dupe closure, feel free to drop into https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign and discuss / ask for input -- at least 2 [tag:css] gold badgers regularly stop by there and sometimes Boltclock, too.

Comment: here is probably the reference about the first charactere : https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#name-start-code-point ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus it was a duplicate for the initial question and now it was changed completely (updated the duplicate list)

Comment: It's working :) thank you. And thank you for the lesson about naming classes!